# Open a folder in File Explorer from a UWP C# app

Tags: c#, uwp

I'd like to open a folder like `C:\myprojects\project1` in File Explorer from a UWP C# app.

I've looked at methods under `Windows.System.Launcher` like `LaunchFolderAsync` and `LaunchUriAsync`, but they don't work.

I understand it's an access/permission issue with `LaunchFolderAsync` but don't understand why launching (`LaunchUriAsync`) an URI like `file://C:\myprojects\project1` is also not working.

Answer (score 8):

For [`LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync), you cannot use this method to launch a URI in the local zone. For example, apps cannot use the **file:///** protocol to access files on the local computer. Instead, you must use the [`Storage APIs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage) to access files.

If you want to open files or folders, you could use picker. For more, you could refer [Open files and folders with a picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).

> I understand it's an access/permission issue with LaunchFolderAsync

[`LaunchFolderAsync(IStorageFolder)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfolderasync) method is use to
launche File Explorer and displays the contents of the [**specified**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders) folder.